# Android enter text on EditText after clearing Focuse

Tags: android

I have simple `EditText` and single layout as widget, You suppose is `TextView`, after click on `TextView` i clearing `EditText` focuse and closing keyboard, now if `TextView` was enabled, after click on `EditText` i disabled that, but after disable that i cant type into `TextEdit`

close keyboard:

```
icon_attachment.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(text_message_box.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
);
```

close `icon_attachment` if it was enabled and type on `EditText` normally

```
@OnClick(R.id.text_message_box)
public void text_message_box(View view) {
    if (!hidden) {
        robot_commands_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        hidden = true;
    }
    text_message_box.setFocusable(true);
    text_message_box.requestFocus();

    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(text_message_box.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}
```

my keyboard can visible programmatically, but i can't type into `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

after more search and try to how can i resolve this problem, adding this option for edit text, thats resolved my problem:

```
android:focusable="true"
```